# Approximate a convex body by polyhedron

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, polyhedra

There are many results how many vertices we need to approximate a convex body. It is known, for a given $\tau > 0$, we need $O(\tau^d)$ vertice of set $X = \{x_1, \dots, x_m\} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ to make $K \subset conv(X) \subset (1+\tau) K $ holds for a convex body K where $conv(X)$ is the convex hull containing $X$ and $(1+\tau)K = \{(1+\tau) x \in \mathbb{R}^d : x \in K \}$. (Ref : Bronstein, Efim M. "Approximation of convex sets by polytopes." Journal of Mathematical Sciences 153.6 (2008): 727-762.)

However, I cannot find any result about polyhedron approximation. That is, I wonder how many closed half spaces we need to approximate a convex body K to make $K \subset \bigcap_{j=1}^m H_j^+ \subset (1+\tau) K$. One obvious bound comes from the upper bound theorem but I guess there are shaper bounds order of $O(\tau^d)$. Is there any reference about this issue?

Comment: Your question would benefit from clarification of your definitions.  It's not clear what $conv$ means, what relationship there is between the vertices you mention and the sets $K$ and $X$, how to interpret $(1+\tau)K$, or which upper bound theorem you are referring to.

Comment: Hi Yly. Thank you for your helpful comments!. I edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: @JaeHyeokShin Did you make progress on your question ? I've ran into a similar pb https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4342694/168758

Comment: Hi @dohmatob At that time, I just ended up using a different approach to solve the related problem so I have no progress on it. I am still interested in the answer and I hope you can find a good answer for your question at this time! =)